# How do I get the value of a cell by row index and column index

Tags: c#, excel

currently i'm doing this:

```
string cellValue = sheet.get_Range("A12", _missing).Value2.ToString();
```

this works but i really need to select a cell by row and column index.

i get a null exception when i try

```
string cellValue = ((Range)sheet.Cells[row, column]).Value2.ToString();
```

any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get an Excel range using row and column numbers in VSTO / C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333202/how-do-i-get-an-excel-range-using-row-and-column-numbers-in-vsto-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Where does the `ArgumentNullException` occur?  Try separating out your code like this and step through it:

```
object rangeObject = sheet.Cells[row, column];
Range range = (Range)rangeObject;
object rangeValue = range.Value2;
string cellValue = rangeValue.ToString();
```

This will show you where the null object is.

Comment: the NullReferenceException happens at 

string cellValue = rangeValue.ToString();

because range.Value2 is null.  i know my sheet is good but i think sheet.Cells[row, column] is the real culprit.

Comment: I think then, that a null `range.Value2` indicates that the cell does not have a value.  If you look at the cell in Excel, is it empty?

Comment: Also, Excel interop uses 1-based indexing.  The problem could be that you are using zero-based indexes which reference an empty cell.  If that is the case, then all you need to do is use `row + 1` and `column + 1` to get the correct cell.

Comment: also you can try using get_value instead of Value2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  The nullref would happen when the cell I was reading was empty.

```
string foo = (((Range) ActiveWorksheet.Cells[row, column]).Value2 != null
            ? ((Range) ActiveWorksheet.Cells[row, column]).Value2.ToString()
            : "Coalesce some false string here...");
```

Notice that you have to check for null *before* you attempt to transform or cast the value.