# How do I get an Excel range using row and column numbers in VSTO / C#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I think the question sums it up. Given two integers for row and column or four integers for row and column for the two corners of a range, how do I get a range object for that range.

Comment: I would start clicking the check mark on the answers that helped you.  People are less likely to help if your percentage is low.

Comment: Select an answer +Dan Crowther. People deserve the points.

Comment: @Wartickler If you look at his profile page, you'll see that he was last seen on SO in 2010. I consider it somewhat unlikely that he'll accept any answers in the foreseeable future :-(

Comment: +Dan Crowther profile also shows him as 'unregistered' .. guess his out

Answer (score 97):

Where the range is multiple cells:

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[3,3]);
```

Where range is one cell:

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) sheet.Cells[1, 1];
```

Comment: Me, too, although I needed to do the same thing (one-cell case) in VBA:`Dim rng As Range` and `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)`

Comment: The `workbook.ActiveSheet;` could be `oExcel.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet;` in which `oExcel` is a Excel instance, right?

Comment: Which in the `[1, 1]` and `[3, 3]` is the row and which the column?

Comment: @mirabilos `dynamic Range[[object RowIndex], [object ColumnIndex]]`

Comment: `Excel.Worksheet` does not have `get_Range` method (I'm using C# in VS 2010)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff In VB.Net you can just use Range on Excel.Worksheet, it may be the same in C#

Comment: @garthhh - Yes, tic's answer works for me. But not this answer.

Answer (score 24):

The given answer will throw an error if used in Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library.
Object does not contain a definition for get_range.
Instead use

```
int countRows = xlWorkSheetData.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
int countColumns = xlWorkSheetData.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
object[,] data = xlWorkSheetData.Range[xlWorkSheetData.Cells[1, 1], xlWorkSheetData.Cells[countRows, countColumns]].Cells.Value2;
```

Comment: I'm using version 15.0 and it also doesn't have get_range, thanks tic, this code works great for me

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting an error stating that "Object does not contain a definition for get_range."

Try following.

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) sheet.Range[sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[3,3]].Cells;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can retrieve value like this

```
string str = (string)(range.Cells[row, col] as Excel.Range).Value2 ;
```

select entire used range

```
Excel.Range range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
```

source :

http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-read-excel.htm

flaming

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same problem I found the quickest solution was to actually scan the rows of the cells I wished to sort, determine the last row with a non-blank element and then select and sort on that grouping.

```
    Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = 0
For r = 3 To 120
   If Cells(r, 2) = "" Then
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(r - 1, 2 + 6))
        rng.Select
        rng.Sort Key1:=Range("h3"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlGuess, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        r = 205
    End If
Next r
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a good short method that seems to work well...

```
Dim x, y As Integer
x = 3: y = 5  
ActiveSheet.Cells(y, x).Select
ActiveCell.Value = "Tada"
```

In this example we are selecting 3 columns over and 5 rows down, then putting "Tada" in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

UsedRange work fine with "virgins" cells, but if your cells are filled in the past, then UsedRange will deliver to you the old value.

For example:

"Think in a Excel sheet that have cells **A1** to **A5** filled with text". In this scenario, [UsedRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheetbase.usedrange(v=vs.100).aspx) must be implemented as:

```
Long SheetRows;
SheetRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
```

A watch to SheetRows variable must display a value of 5 after the execution of this couple of lines.

> Q1: But, what happen if the value of A5 is deleted?
>
> A1: The value of SheetRows would be 5
>
> Q2: Why this?
>
> A2: Because MSDN define UsedRange property as:
>
> *Gets a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range object that represents all*
>   *the cells that have contained a value **at any time.***

---

So, the question is: Exist some/any workaround for this behavior?

I think in 2 alternatives:

1. Avoid deleting the content of the cell, preferring deletion of the whole row (right click in the row number, then "delete row".
2. Use [CurrentRegion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.currentregion(v=office.14).aspx) instead of UsedRange property as follow:

---

```
Long SheetRows;
SheetRows = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want like `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` , you can do it.

just use the following code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

string xlBk = @"D:\Test.xlsx";
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWb;
Excel.Worksheet xlWs;

Excel.Range rng;
int iLast;

xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlBk, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

xlWs = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

iLast = xlWs.Rows.Count;
rng = (Excel.Range)xlWs.Cells[iLast, 1];
iLast = rng.get_End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

Comment: Thanks sinsedrix!

Comment: And Column is just like this, right? Then, if you use UsedRange foreach in addition, row by row, column by column check, you can get like 'new UsedRange' not knowing what the row/column is the last row/column.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, works!

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet = xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Series series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Range[xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 13], xlWorkSheet.Cells[pp, 13]].Cells;
series1.Values = rng;
```