# C#/WPF: Defining an EXCEL range through row and column number

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, range, office-interop

I have tried this

> [How do I get an Excel range using row and column numbers in VSTO / C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333202/how-do-i-get-an-excel-range-using-row-and-column-numbers-in-vsto-c)

but it throw an undefined com exception

what I would like is something like (pseudocode)

```
Range myRange = new Range(new cell(1,1), cell(3,3));
```

so that I can then use it with (pseudocode again)

```
ws.myRange.Interior.Color = XlRgbColor.rgbDarkGray;
```

thank you

Comment: Did u check my example ?

Comment: Yep sorry for being late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that out:

```
Range range1 = ws.Range[ws.Cells[1, j], ws.Cells[1, j+1]];
```

Here, Range is :

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range
```